# Are there direct flights from Moscow to Tenerife?

Tags: air-travel, moscow, tenerife

Are there direct flights from Moscow to Tenerife? If not, what is the best way to get there? I'm interested in Los Cristianos. As I understand it, regularly ships from the Spanish mainland go there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what it appears having looked on travel comparison sites for available flights there are no direct flights between Moscow & Tenerife. You didn't mention any particular date of travel so I chose a week departing  3rd April, returning 10th April 2013. Sample results from the comparison site **kayak.co.uk** indicate flights with a stop over in either Barcelona or Madrid (note the duration of travel).

[image]

Tenerife being a part of the Canary Islands are located directly west of Morocco, and are far from mainland spain. I thinking getting on any type of sea faring vessel from Spain to Tenerife is not ideal(unless you were planning a cruise).

If I were you, I am aware that EasyJet recently started flying between London Gatwick & Moscow, and also fly from London Gatwick to Tenerife (flying time approximately 4 hours). I would strongly suggest consulting them, as an alternative:

http://www.easyjet.com/en

Like I say you haven't mentioned date of travel, prices may vary considerably if it were June instead of April (as I gave in the example above).

Answer (score 3):

Yes there are flights direct from Moscow to Tenerife, although these are not your regularly scheduled variety.  There are charters operated by [ВИМ Авиа](http://www.vim-avia.com/) and [Transaero](http://www.transaero.ru) which can be booked from [Chartex](http://www.chartex.ru/step1.asp?sTariff=2&CityFromID=5359&CityToID=4471) as well as charters operated by [Aeroflot](http://www.aeroflot.ru) and [Н5](http://www.iflyltd.ru/) that can be booked from [Ticket-Charter](http://www.ticket-charter.ru/timetables/spain.php).  These are chartered flights, so restrictions and other issues may befall them.

As far as other possibilities are concerned you can find flights from [SkyScanner](http://www.skyscanner.ru), which will give you a 1 stop flight to Tenerife via various destinations in Europe.